# android.R.id not found after Gradle update

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I am working on an android project that used Gradle `2.3.3` (at this point, there was no compiling issues). I upgraded Gradle to version `3.0.1`, and made the required adjustments.

I removed retrolambda. I changed the keywords to use the new dependency configurations.

But my project doesn't compile, because it seems that `android.R.*` elements are not found anymore. The errors I have are :

```
Error:(524, 27) error: cannot find symbol variable id
Error:(625, 122) error: cannot find symbol variable id
Error:(74, 63) error: cannot find symbol variable color
```

on the following ids : `android.R.id.home`, and `android.R.color.white`.

What changed on Gradle 3.0.1 that could have triggered these errors ?

**EDIT :** I already tried to clear/invalidate caches, restart, sync Project with gradle files, clean, rebuild...
A coworker tried to compile the code on his computer : same error - it doesn't look like it is a cache issue.

Comment: have you tried clean/rebuild or invalidate caches and restart ? if not ,you should , this type of errors many times get fixed by these.

Comment: Yes, I tried multiple times. It didn't change anything.

Comment: Last time I manually cleared `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\.android\build-cache` and 
`C:\Users\<username>\.gradle\caches`and I removed the `build` folder at the root of the project. So AS had to rebuild everything and it solved the issue.

Comment: @Eselfar No changes either :(

Comment: still getting same issue ?

Comment: @chandanicpatel yes.

Comment: delete this line : import android.R; and import it again

Comment: you can downaload gradle manually and select this gradle by file->Setting->Build,Execution,Deployment->Gradle `select local gradle` and set the path here
`https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.3-all.zip`

Comment: @chandanicpatel the line "import android.R" was never here :)

Comment: @VishalYadav no changes with that either